# java: (String[])List.toArray() gives ClassCastException

Tags: java, list, classcastexception, toarray

The following code (run in android) always gives me a ClassCastException in the 3rd line:

```
final String[] v1 = i18nCategory.translation.get(id);
final ArrayList<String> v2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(v1));
String[] v3 = (String[])v2.toArray();
```

It happens also when v2 is Object[0] and also when there are Strings in it.
Any Idea why?

Comment: You may want to read about Covariance and Contravariance -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Java

Comment: What about the case where T is an interface with a factory method for instantiation.

Comment: @LaceCard - this is only very indirectly related to covariance/contravariance.  The real issue is that this is a direct consequence of the specified behaviour of the `toArray()` method.

Answer (score 266, accepted):

This is because when you use

```
 toArray()
```

it returns an Object[], which can't be cast to a String[] (even tho the contents are Strings) This is because the toArray method only gets a

```
List
```

and not

```
List<String>
```

as generics are a source code only thing, and not available at runtime and so it can't determine what type of array to create.

use

```
toArray(new String[v2.size()]);
```

which allocates the right kind of array (String[] and of the right size)

Comment: @Kaleb - not true.  Or at least that's not the original reason.  The `toArray` methods existed before the collection classes were generic.

Comment: This is the correct solution, but not the correct explanation. You can't cast Object[] to Double[] because it's a language feature, nothing more. It doesn't have to do with Generics. You can cast Object to Double assuming that's it is truly a Double. So logically, you could do the same with an array, but it's simply not part of the language. If you cast Object to Double there will be a runtime check to make sure Object actually IS a Double. If you cast Double to Object there is no runtime check, since Object is in the inheritance hierarchy of Double.

Comment: When doing this in IntelliJ, I get a warning to use `toArray(new String[0])` rather: "In older Java versions using pre-sized array was recommended as the reflection call which is necessary to create an array of proper size was quite slow. However since late updates of OpenJDK 6 this call was intrinsified, making the performance of the empty array version the same and sometimes even better. Also passing pre-sized array is dangerous for a concurrent collection as a race is possible between the `size` and `toArray` call."

Answer (score 36):

You are using the wrong `toArray()`

Remember that Java's generics are mostly syntactic sugar. An ArrayList doesn't actually know that all its elements are Strings.

To fix your problem, call [`toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29). In your case,

```
String[] v3 = v2.toArray(new String[v2.size()]);
```

Note that the genericized form `toArray(T[])` returns `T[]`, so the result does not need to be explicitly cast.

Answer (score 2):

Using `toArray` from the [JDK 11 Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray()), you can solve the more general problem this way:

```java
Object[] v1 = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"}; // or array of another type
String[] v2 = Arrays.stream(v1)
    .<String>map((Object v) -> v.toString()).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] v3 = v2.toArray(new String[0]);
```

also does the trick,
note that you don't even need to cast anymore once the right ArrayType is given to the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] str = new String[list.size()];
str = (String[]) list.toArray(str);
```

Use like this.

Comment: Please! Format your code! Select all of it at press "ctrl + k", or add " ` " before the first letter of code and at the last one another one. You can also select "{}" in the help at the top when writing the answer!