# Why does List.toArray() return an array of Object?

Tags: java, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why does List<String>.toArray() return Object[] and not String[]? how to work around this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909747/why-does-liststring-toarray-return-object-and-not-string-how-to-work-ar)

See this code example :

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("hello");
    list.add("world");
    Object [] array = list.toArray();
```

Why does the method `toArray()` return an array of `Object` ? Other `List` methods such as `get()` , `remove()` are able to return the type of objects in the list.

Comment: @SuperChafouin please do some research before posting a question.

Comment: Ok, this answers to my question : [http://stackoverflow.com/a/7909755/1075341](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7909755/1075341)
I mark my question as duplicate.

Comment: For those interested in that question, i found the best way to understand is to try to program your own implementation of `toArray` using generics or to look at `ArrayList` code, for example.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `toArray(String[] a)` which will return array of string type or basically array of specified type.
the toArray method returns object as it acts as bridge between Collection based and List based API.

Answer (score 0):

I believe is returns Object in order to be generic Most likely it has to deal with memory allocation issues. The system doesn't have to know your exact type inorder to allocate an array of Objects. You don't run into this with get and remove since it's only returning one item.

But I will upvote your question in hope someone can confirm my answer or correct me.

Answer (score 0):

The Java [List#toArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29) explains it.

Comment: The answer was accidentally formatted as code -- fixed!

Comment: From now on, please refer to a valid documentation. The link was pointing to Java 1.4, there is new documentation in [Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray()) and [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray()).

Answer (score 0):

`toArray()` has to construct new array object and fill it up. But because of *runtime generic type erasure* `toArray()` does not know what is the actual type of the elements. because of that creates array of Object (`Object[]`). Use `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)` if you want typed array.