# Convert ArrayList to Array

Tags: java, arrays, exception, arraylist, null

I'm having a little trouble converting an array list to an array in java.

I have a class called Table which contains an array list called `applicants` which takes Strings. When I use my `toArray()` function it doesn't seem to convert the array list into an array.

I know this because when i run the listArray() function it gives the error:

`java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Here is the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Table {
    public ArrayList<String> applicants;
    public String appArray[];

    public Table() {
        applicants = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void addApplicant(String app) {
        applicants.add(app);
    }

    public void toArray() {
        int x = applicants.size();
        String[] appArray = new String[x];
        appArray = applicants.toArray(appArray);
    }

    public void list() {
        for (int i = 0; i < applicants.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(applicants.get(i));
        }
    }

    public void listArray() {
        for (int i = appArray.length; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(appArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is because you are shadowing the `appArray` field in your method here:

```
 int x = applicants.size();
 String[] appArray = new String[x];
 appArray = applicants.toArray(appArray);
```

You create a new local variable called `appArray` when you should be using the `appArray` field you already have declared in your class.

You should do

```
public void toArray()
{
    appArray = applicants.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: Can I ask as someone interested in this answer, why do you need to cast the ArrayList to a String[] type? As it is already this type, why won't applicants.toArray() work?

Comment: @AndrewMartin the function returns `Object[]` so you should cast it to your class type array.in that way the function will know the type of array to return. Another alternative would be using `List#toArray(T[] array)`, look at the `ArrayList#toArray` code for an example: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.toArray%28java.lang.Object[]%29

Comment: Or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007998/why-does-list-toarray-return-an-array-of-object

Comment: This code throws java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;  I think you need to say appArray = applicants.toArray(new String[application.size()]);

Comment: @krico You're correct. I've fixed my code to use the overloaded `toArray(T[])` method. I thought you were referring to the first snippet.

Answer (score 1):

```
appArray = new String[applicants.size()];
int index = 0;
for(String app:applicants){
    appArray [index] = app;
    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because both your ArrayList and Array should only have strings you can do this.

```
appArray = applicants.toArray(new String[0]);
```

More information in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29).