# Why isn't List.toArray() generic?

Tags: java

Why isn't List.toArray() generic? Why must you give the type as an argument (and usually create a new empty instance)?

```
public Object[] toArray()
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray()

---

Update: I have since learned that generic array creation is not allowed, but I believe that it should be. Is there any reason why it's not allowed?

```
Main.java:28: error: generic array creation
        T[] ret = new T[size()];
```

http://ideone.com/3nX0cz

---

Update: Ok I believe this is the answer:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays

Not because it is directly relevant, but indirectly relevant. There is nothing inherently wrong with `new T[size()]`, where `MyList<String>` would be turned into `new String[size()]`, but T could itself be a parameterized type. So if you were to create `MyList<Set<Integer>>`, then `T` would equal `Set<Integer>` and the compiler would try to create `new Set<Integer>[size()]`, which could lead to the problem in the link when returned. Someone tried to give an answer along these lines but that answer has since been deleted so I forgot who it was.

Comment: There is an overloaded version of `toArray` that is generic

Comment: Scroll slightly further down.

Comment: @Dgrin91 But you have to pass in an array instance as a parameter, which is what the OP was asking about.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T[]%29

Comment: To maintain backward compatibility.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909747/why-does-liststring-toarray-return-object-and-not-string-how-to-work-ar/7909764#7909764

Comment: No need for scrolling, its the next one :)

Comment: @GriffeyDog Everything is an Object. Any generic T will also be an Object. I don't believe that is why.

Comment: You are right, you can't create a `new Set<Integer>[size()]`. But the problem is mode obvious. In your `.class` file **there is no trace of type `T`**. 

You cannot check _anything_ about `T` - you read a lot of restrictions in that referred article (like `instanceof`, `new T()`, ...) - unless you pass the **runtime Class information** (`Class<T>`) there. 

So, if you create an instance of `MyList<T>`, the **actual value ot type `T` is not stored** along with the instance itself.

Answer (score 4):

This method is supposed to *create* a new array. But, if you don't have the `Class` information of `T`, you cannot do that.

You cannot say `T[] array = new T[list.size()];`

If you pass the array as a parameter (like in the other method) there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

The complete answer is: because the implementation of `toArray()` is not able to construct the `T[]` array it's supposed to return to you without the "exemplar" array.  Look at the source code of the generic overload of `toArray( T[] )` in `AbstractCollection` to see the difference.

They also could have done it with a `Class< T >` argument.  But at least with an exemplar you can allocate the space yourself if you want to (and it's nearly impossible to produce an instance of `Class< G< S > >` for a generic type `G< S >`).

Answer (score 0):

Because of the nature of Generics in Java. Due to erasure, there is no type information available during runtime, so the no-arg version can only return an array of Objects.

Comment: @GriffeyDog They couldn't change the return type unless also adding T parameter which is what Kayaman is saying.  You are right that they created an overload to maintain backward compatibility since the original `toArray()` was there since 1.2 and the generic since only 1.5.