# What is the proper cast in this case?

Tags: java, exception, casting

I have the following class that has the capability of performing a deep copy of itself.

```
public class XPolygon {
    private XVector[] points;

    XPolygon(XVector... points)
    {
        this.points = points;
    }

    public XPolygon copy()
    {
        return new XPolygon((XVector[])Arrays.stream(this.points).map(XVector::copy).toArray());
    }
}
```

Please consider this to be an academic exercise. When the `copy` method of an instance is called, the following exception is generated:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LXVector;
    at XPolygon.copy(XPolygon.java:17)
```

What is the proper way of calling the `XPolygon` constructor to prevent an error for occurring?

Comment: Suitable dupe: [why does List.toArray() return Object\[\] and not String\[\]? how to work around this?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7909747)

Comment: Thanks for the information!