# Why does Collection<E>#toArray() not return E[]?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, collections

Why does [`Collection<E>.toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28%29) (non-parameterized method) return `Object[]`?

Is it one of those consciously taken decisions? Is there any reason why the `toArray()` method would not be able to return a `E[]`, if it wanted to?

Comment: type erasure is the reason. java does not know what T is at runtime - therefore it cannot create an array of the appropriate type. The other, "typesafe" variant of toArray requires a "prototype" array with the right type (that is fixed at compile time!) which it can copy.

Comment: It's historical. The method predates generics, and was kept in its existing form to avoid breaking legacy code.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. I don't see any way to get the class of `E` in that method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Java's Collection<E>.toArray\(\) return an Object\[\] rather than an E\[\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173495/why-does-javas-collectione-toarray-return-an-object-rather-than-an-e). Please ignore the post I gave when voting - I pasted the wrong link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because an array of type `T` cannot be instantiated without knowing the type `Class<T>`. Contrast this with `toArray(T[] array)`, which has the following source (example from `LinkedList`). Notice that the passed-in array is used not only as a possible container, but to possibly instantiate a new array of that type. This code throws an exception if `T` is not a superclass of `E`; if objects can't be added to the array.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
    if (a.length < size)
        a = (T[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(
                            a.getClass().getComponentType(), size);
    int i = 0;
    Object[] result = a;
    for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next)
        result[i++] = x.item;

    if (a.length > size)
        a[size] = null;

    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generics in Java are implemented using a technique called type erasure. This means that an instance of a generic class does not have any information about its generic type.  Consider this

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.toArray();
```

since list does not know about its generic type it can create only Object[]

Answer (score 0):

Array containers have an associated item data type, preserved at runtime. If you construct an Object array and then add strings, this object won't be castable to String[]:

```
    Object[] objArr = new Object[] {"a", "b"};
    String[] strArr = (String[]) objArr; //Produces ClassCastException
```

You can also notice how this array property is used at runtime when you add items of an incorrect type to an array:

```
    String[] strArr = new String[] {"a", "b"};
    Object[] objArr = (Object[]) strArr; //Legal this time
    objArr[0] = 15; //Produces ArrayStoreException
```

Generic type arguments are erased at runtime, so the JVM doesn't know what specific array type to create at runtime when you call toArray().