# How to convert an arraylist to a multidimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` object which its values are arrays of `Object`. I want to convert it to an array. This is the summary of what i did:

```
ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
Object[] row = new Object[4];
result.add(row);
Object[][] arrayResult = result.toArray();
```

but I get an error that i can't cast it to an `Object[][]`. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to something like these:

```
ArrayList<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>(); // 1
Object[] row = new Object[4];
result.add(row);
Object[][] arrayResult = result.toArray(new Object[0][0]); // 2
```

1. You should have a type parameter (don't really affect the error, but good practice).
2. [`toArray` with no arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29) would just give you a `Object[]`, you need to give it [an array as a "example"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29). This is caused by something called "type erasure", which you can read a bit from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173495/why-does-javas-collectione-toarray-return-an-object-rather-than-an-e).