# Java - Most efficient way to convert a TreeSet<String> into a String[]?

Tags: java, arrays, string, treeset

I was doing this:

```
(String[]) myTreeSet.toArray();
```

but that gives me a ClassCastException at runtime.

The only thing I can think of doing is just making an array first and then iterating through each element in myTreeSet and adding it to the array. It seems like there must be a better way than this. Is there or should I just do this?

Thanks.

Comment: http://forums.devshed.com/java-help-9/treeset-to-an-array-401225.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
String[] result = myTreeSet.toArray(new String[myTreeSet.size()]);
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could someone explain why my way threw the exception, and why this way doesn't?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690351/java-stringlist-toarray-gives-classcastexception

Comment: how about reverse

Answer (score 3):

When using `toArray()` the following happens: a new Object array is being allocated by using `new Object[size]` and each element from the array will be a reference to one of your strings element. Even if actually points to strings, it's an array with the type `Object`.

When using `toArray(T[] a)` the following happens: a new T arrays is being allocated by using

```
java.lang.reflect.Array
              .newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), size)
```

and each from the array will be a reference to one of your strings because `a.getClass().getComponentType` will return `String.class` in your case. This time, it's an array with the type String.