# Can't return a Object[] casted as String[]

Tags: java, arrays, object, java.lang.class

```
public String[] getAllKeys (){

    Object[] keysCopy = new Object[keys.size()];
    keysCopy = keys.toArray();

    return ((String[])keysCopy());
}
```

Why this gives me Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String??

Comment: Use the overloaded method `toArray(T[] arr)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [java: (String\[\])List.toArray() gives ClassCastException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690351/java-stringlist-toarray-gives-classcastexception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you have object array and `Object[]` cannot be cast to `String[]`. The reverse is possible. Its because `Object` [IS NOT A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `String` and `String` [IS A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `Object`.

If you are ***sure that*** the content of `keys` is *collection* of `String`, then you can use `keys.toArray(new String[keys.size()]);`

```
public String[] getAllKeys(){
    return keys.toArray(new String[keys.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Or in case of Streams: `keys.stream().toArray(String[]::new)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
`return Arrays.copyOf(keysCopy, keysCopy.length, String[].class);`
```

Answer (score 0):

An `Object[]` is not a `String[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works.

```
public String[] getAllKeys (){
Object[] keysCopy = new Object[keys.size()];
keysCopy = keys.toArray(new String[0]);
return (String[]) keysCopy;
}
```

For more you can read this [post] ([How to convert object array to string array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018750/how-to-convert-object-array-to-string-array-in-java))