# Different Datasets

Tags: java, arrays

So I'd like to copy a variable in Java without them sharing the same dataset.
The variable is an array called `ChunkSection[] tsec` and I'd like to copy it to `ChunkSection[] sec` but without the two having any sort of relationship. I've tried .clone() but it didn't work.

```
ChunkSection[] sec = null;
tsec = fromChunk.i().clone();
for (ChunkSection s : tsec) {
    ArrayList<ChunkSection> chs = new ArrayList<>();
    chs.add(s);
    sec = (ChunkSection[]) chs.toArray();               <-----
}
```

The code above generates a ClassCastException on the line that arrow points to.

Comment: Use the overloaded `toArray(T[] arr)` method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java: (String\[\])List.toArray() gives ClassCastException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690351/java-stringlist-toarray-gives-classcastexception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Arrays.copyOf to make a copy of an array.

```
ChunkSection [] sec = Arrays.copyOf(tsec, tsec.length);
```